# preg_match() Compilation failed

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-match, minify, w3-total-cache

I cannot solve this error:

> PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at
>   offset 0 in
>   /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/Minify_Plugin.php
>   on line 1107, referer: https:// MY-HOME.COM/

The line 1107 is:

```
if ( $expr != '' && preg_match( '~' . $expr . '~i', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] )) {
```

Thank you in advance

**EDIT:** This question is different because I'm talking about Minify_plugin.php (w3 Total Cache) file for first time here.

Comment: What is the value of `$expr`?

Comment: Try *quoting* `$expr`, e.g. `preg_quote($expr, '~')`

Comment: So I have same question. Can you solve it please?